# jQuery dropdown menu using prepend trigger

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use jQuery to prepend a trigger to a menu then have that trigger toggle child elements. The code below doesn't open the sub menus when using jQuery prepend, can any one suggest a fix?

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">Item 1</li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Sub Item 1</li>
      <li>Sub Item 2</li>
      <li class="menu-item-has-children">Sub Item 3</li>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>Sub Sub Item 1</li>
          <li>Sub Sub Item 2</li>
          <li>Sub Sub Item 3</li>
          <li>Sub Sub Item 4</li>
          <li>Sub Sub Item 5</li>
        </ul>
      <li>Sub Item 4</li>
      <li>Sub Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li {
 list-style-type:none;
}
.open {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:red;
  color:#fff;
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-align:center;
}
.sub-menu {
  display:none;
}
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.menu-item-has-children').prepend ('<a class="open">+</a>');
    jQuery('.open').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).next('.sub-menu').toggle();
  });
});
```

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aLo6k7mo/5/)

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery menu with sub menu trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371370/jquery-menu-with-sub-menu-trigger)

Comment: `jQuery(this).next` isn't going to work because the only siblings `.open` has are text nodes presumably.  You would need to either cache `this` before descending into the click function closure and reference that variable (maybe using `let`?) or use `jQuery(this.parentNode)`, but in any case, your markup is wrong anyway.  You can't have an element that isn't an `li` as a child of `ul`.  You're nesting needs fixed.

Comment: So, what I mean to say is your issue can easily be corrected, but please cleanup your markup first.  Invalid markup may result in unpredictable behaviour later on.

Comment: Yes, with the markup fixed your code works fine: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/aLo6k7mo/7/)

Comment: I just noticed that too, @empiric.  You could probably write that as an answer.  Looks like OP had the logic right, but just had a minor issue with the markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is not the JS but your HTML.

As Joseph Marikle stated: Your [`ul`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)

> permitted content zero or more `<li>` elements, which in turn often
>   contain nested `<ol>` or `<ul>` elements.

must not have any child-elements other than `li`.

In your case the element `.open` does not have a sibling therefor`.next()` will not find `.sub-menu`.

If you move your inner `ul` inside the `li.menu-item-has-children` you JS works just fine:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.menu-item-has-children').prepend('<a class="open">+</a>');
  jQuery('.open').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).next('.sub-menu').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.open {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">Item 1
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Sub Item 1</li>
      <li class="menu-item-has-children">Sub Item 3
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>Sub Sub Item 1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Sub Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```